# how to send data from Ambari dashboard to s3 using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ambari

I have .csv file which is stored in Ambari Dashboard,Is there any possibility to send that .csv file from Ambari Dashboard to s3.

Comment: where is Ambari Installed? on your EC2 server?

Comment: It is set up in bluemix.

Comment: Do you have access to the command line? if yes, then you can use aws cli